# Configuring ASP .NET MVC Core controller instantiation without using ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In the good old days of OWIN, prior to aspnet core, one could configure ASP.NET WebApi by passing in a HttpConfiguration object. In there one could, among other things configure the ControllerActivator etc... if you would like to.... e.g.

```
appBuilder.UseWebApi(webApiConfig)
```

Is there a similar way one can do this in ASP.NET MVC Core, avoiding the using the WebHostBuilder (either directly or via the StartUp convention)?

e.g. without using something like:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()             
.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => 
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new 
    ControllerActivator()))
```

(The only overloads one can use on .UseMVC takes an IRouteBuilder ... Or is there a way to get to the ServiceCollection to manipulate the ControllerActivator?)

EDIT:

There is an option to create a IServiceProvider using the ServiceCollection class. The IServiceProvider can then be passed as an argument to the ApplicationBuilder like so:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddMvcCore();
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection
                .AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new ControllerActivator())
                .AddLogging()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            ApplicationBuilder builder = new ApplicationBuilder(serviceProvider);
            builder.UseMvc();

            return builder.Build();
```

However, this leaves me with as exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory'
```

Investigating further....

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I've created a [HttpMessageHandler](https://github.com/MCGPPeters/Aranea.HttpMessageHandler) that can take a RequestDelegate (or middleware) so that it can be called directly using an HttpClient (a port of Damian Hickey's [OwinHttpMessageHandler](https://github.com/damianh/OwinHttpMessageHandler)).

Now, in the 'old' OWIN stack, one could pass in the HttpConfiguration directly while setting up the request / middleware pipeline... I want to do something similar...

Answer (score 0):

So... there are a few required services that need to be present to at least get the pipeline running without exceptions. My primary goal was to add a custom IControllerActivator. This is what I ended up with (after peeking into WebHostBuilder [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L255)):

```
 var listener = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
 var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
 serviceCollection.AddMvcCore();

 var serviceProvider = serviceCollection
     .AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new ControllerActivator())
     .AddLogging()
     .AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(listener)
     .AddOptions()
     .AddSingleton<ObjectPoolProvider, DefaultObjectPoolProvider>()
     .BuildServiceProvider();
```

...

```
 ApplicationBuilder builder = new ApplicationBuilder(serviceProvider);
 builder.UseMvc();

 return builder.Build();
```

...

Hope it helps someone..